# Окончания имен античных героев

Tags: словообразование

Пытаюсь понять хоть какую-то логику в добавлении и убавлении окончаний античных - греческих и римских - имен. Почему Ахилл, но Геркулес? Почему Нерон, в то время как по-латыни будет Nero и никакого Н на конце?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ищите логику, ищите закономерность. Или хотя бы статистику.
С Неронами-Платонами и прочими все более или менее понятно. Н добавлено для придания именам "мужского рода".

Что касается Ахилла и Геркулеса, то вы ошибаетесь. Ахиллес используется как минимум не реже Ахилла. Тем более - Геракл. Так что вопрос правильнее бы ставить так: "Почему в этих случаях возможны два варианта написания?" и только после этого: "Какой из вариантов используется чаще и почему?".
На первый вопрос ответ достаточно прост. Вариант без греческих и латинских окончаний использовался в дореволюционный период, когда классическое образование требовало хотя бы минимального знания "классических" языков. При этом, естественно, было понимание, что все эти -ес и -ус - не более чем флексии именительного падежа, т.е. не требуют перенесения при переводе. С утерей классического подхода к образованию, окончания стали восприниматься как часть имени собственного. Отсюда и два варианта написания. какой из них выбрать, автор обычно решает сам. Возможно, не в последнюю очередь играет роль и длина имени.